# Creating A Typedef In C++

Tags: c++, types, typedef

### What Searching I've Done:

Hello, so typedefs are a new topic to me, and I have already read a page about them. (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) But that's the best information I could find, the only problem is because I have no idea how it's working enough, I'm unable to rework it and use it for my situation.

Also, for the heads up; I'm trying to create a type like the 'App' type that you write when creating a CLR Form in C++. (Visual Studio) The only difference is it will be used for a different reason, so don't copy the code from it please.

### My Code:

```
#pragma once

class Application {
public:
    typedef class App;  // Runnable C++ object (TEST PLEASE DON'T JUDGE)

private:
    void Run(App myApp) {   // ERROR: incomplete type is not allowed

    }
};
```

### How You Can Help Me:

- Explain what a typedef is used for. (Examples will work)
- Explain in what type I should create the 'App' type. (Eg. Class, String,       Int, etc.) Or explain in what other way I can do so.
- You can also just create an example with comments explaining.

Thanks for the help! I tried to keep this question real explainable and sleek.

Comment: Hard pressed to beat the cppreference link you have there. Try this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef or this: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/ . Note: You can also use the `using` keyword. More here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Comment: Typedef can be used to be synonymous with types. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef

Comment: I'm not sure you need a typedef, can you explain more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Well, I'm seeking to make a framework that allows users to use the Swing library in C++. And the App is needed as to explain the project or class that is main. (This would be the main of the Swing control application) But I have not an idea in doing so, I have a small team here to help with Java, but I'm the only C++ developer. I know C++ up to about below intermediate, so I believe I'm able. Just tell me what you think. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, typedef simply creates an alias for another type, such that referencing the new type is identical to referencing the original type.

```
// create a alias for the int type
typedef int my_new_type;

// here a and b have the same type
int a = 1;
my_new_type b = 1;
```

The above is a contrived example, generally the types you use typedef for would be more complex (like `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>`). For your use case, I'm not sure a typedef is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```
typedef Application App;
```

But I'm not sure why you don't just do

```
class Application {
private:
    void Run(Application myApp) {

    }
};
```

As for usage, one use for `typedef` is to define types whose underlying type may vary depending on the build configuration, target platform and compiler. For example if you are writing a game that will run on PS4 and XBOX One, you might be using two different compilers depending on which platform you are building for.

```
    #if defined(MSVC) 
        typedef __int64 TInt64;
    #elif defined(GCC)
        typedef int64_t TInt64;
    #endif
```

This allows more of your code to be platform-agnostic and abstracts away compiler/platform details making app code more readable and encapsulating the assumptions we're interested in. It also reduces codebase size and preprocessing which can improve your compile times.

```
// We can assume this will be exactly 64 bits on all our target platforms.
TInt64 myInt = 0x1000000000000000;
```

P.S. Although it doesn't cover `typedef`s in general [Marshall Cline's C++ FAQ](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~mjh/docs/c++-faq/) is an great resource for beginners and experts alike.

Comment: I don't think typedef is the right approach here, as a private class method implicitly gets access to the class it self. My guess is the OP has some interface they want to pass into the `Run` function, but I am not familiar with the CLR Form library they referenced.